# What is oracledbconsoleorcl?

Tags: oracle

What is oracledbconsoleorcl?  It seems like it is the source of a lot of CPU thrashing on my system and when I disable it, the thrashing goes away.

I know that it is probably required, but I'm curious.   That other site is the only place I've seen an answer, and they want me to pay for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a service that is responsible for the Oracle Enterprise Manager Database Control.

Comment: So many users can simply disable this service (assuming they were happy to use SqlPlus to manage their database).  Is that correct?